# Which GUI svn client allows searching through history?

Tags: gui, subversion

I'm looking for GUI tool that allows searching svn history, and more than just log messages.

Comment: Zend studio has this built in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to search through an entire svn repository, one setup that comes to mind is to serve the repository over HTTP with [WebSVN](http://websvn.tigris.org/), [ViewVC](http://viewvc.org/) or other similar package, plug in your favorite website indexer, and use a web browser to perform searches.

Comment: What website indexer would you recommend?

Comment: @Tshepang: I have zero experience in this matter. Many people like Google, but I think it's not free (even for personal or nonprofit use) (unless your svn is publicly readable, of course).

Comment: I was just curious, since I've hardly ever seen such an indexer for a non-public web resource.

Comment: @Tshepang: There are at least three choices in Ubuntu: htdig, mnogosearch, swish-e.

Answer (score -1):

Just try SmartSVN, seems a bit overkill to install HTTP server just for this.

http://www.smartsvn.com/